# Mysql match url against saved regex expression

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a table in which I am saving the regex expression that later I used to detect the urls.

Now I want if I enter url in search field then in the database query will fetch all the records(regex expression) that catch the url:

for example in the db I have saved this expression

```
.*\/[a-z0-9]{0,}\.gif\?abc=[0-9]&rnd=[0-9]{1,}.*
```

Now If I search this url

```
cnzz.mmstat.com/9.gif?abc=1&rnd=162146281
```

then it should automatically fetch the record where regex detect this url.

I am using MySql and Core PHP

Comment: Arjun, please have a look at my answer man. Let me know if it works?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any capture groups in your regex. Use this:

```
.*\/[a-z0-9]{0,}\.gif\?abc=[0-9]&rnd=([0-9]{1,}.*)
```

So this gives the last set of numbers as a capture group. You can test it at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tQ7yG7/1).

Now using [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) you can get the last `id` of the URL and that can be used to make your calculations.

**Sample Code**

```
<?php
preg_match('.*\/[a-z0-9]{0,}\.gif\?abc=[0-9]&rnd=([0-9]{1,}.*)',
    "cnzz.mmstat.com/9.gif?abc=1&rnd=162146281", $matches);
$id = $matches[0];

echo "The id is: {$matches[0]}\n";
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. but I think you didn't understood my question. I have made a regex expression that detect a url and then I have saved that expression in DB. Now if I enter a url then in the database query should fetch all the expression that detect that particular url

Comment: @ArjunThakur Oh man, you wanna use this Regex in MySQL to get all the IDs is it?

Comment: @parveen no I don't want to use the regex to get the IDs. the expression is already saved in the DB. Now I have one url and I want to fetch the records(regex expressions) that match against the url. One way is to fetch all the records(expression saved in DB) and then using preg_match I match all the expression against URL But this process takes lots of time, So I don't want to use it

Comment: @ArjunThakur Er... Not clear. Well... Can you explain in a better way, or let's wait and take your time while others can answer. `:)`